# Postgresql: create a table and delete if exist

Tags: postgresql

I'm running a batch of postgres queries from a python script. Some queries are as follow:

```
create table xxx [...]
```

Usually I get the following error:

```
psycopg2.ProgrammingError: relation "xxx" already exists
```

I know that i can manually delete the xxx table, but i ask me if there are a way to avoid this error. Something like delete xxx table if exist.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, there's [`DROP TABLE IF EXISTS`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/sql-droptable.html):

> `IF EXISTS`
>
> Do not throw an error if the table does not exist. A notice is issued in this case.

This option is available since version 8.2.

Comment: And... there are some like: 
Create table if doesn't exist?

Comment: Yes, you can use `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS` since version 9.1.

Comment: Can you tell me what is wrong here? I can't run this query, version 9.1.9:
create table if not exists fin_stat as select * from fin_dm